# IMACRO's Script open 2 new tabs with specific URL's

Tags: javascript, instagram, imacros

I am trying to get an IMACRO's script working so that i can go to a persons page in www.iconosquare.com and then open the first photo in a new tab, secondly I want to click view all likes (So it shows as many likes as it can) and then one by one open the users in a new tab and follow them and then close the tab and go to the next person! After like 100 users I want it to close the image tab and go to the next image! I have half of it working but I can't figure out what goes wrong!

This is a part of my code(100 repeats is alot of code)

```
    VERSION BUILD=8881205 RECORDER=FX
    SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
    SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
    SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 2
    TAB T=1
    TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=A ATTR=CLASS:lienPhotoGrid&&HREF:#/detail/* EXTRACT=HREF
    TAB OPEN
    TAB T=2
    URL GOTO={{!EXTRACT}}
    TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=CLASS:unLike<SP>allCommentsLikes<SP>majuscule
    WAIT SECONDS=2
SET !EXTRACT NULL
    TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=CLASS:unLike&&HREF:#/user/*/ EXTRACT=HREF
    TAB OPEN
    TAB T=3
    URL GOTO=http://iconosquare.com/viewer.php#/user/*/
    WAIT SECONDS=3
    TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=CLASS:followAction<SP>user-relation-action&&HREF:#&&TXT:Follow
    TAB CLOSE
    WAIT SECONDS=1
    TAG POS=2 TYPE=A ATTR=CLASS:unLike&&HREF:#/user/*/ EXTRACT=HREF
    TAB OPEN
    TAB T=3
    URL GOTO={{!EXTRACT}}
    TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=CLASS:followAction<SP>user-relation-action&&HREF:#&&TXT:Follow
    TAB CLOSE
    WAIT SECONDS=1
    TAG POS=3 TYPE=A ATTR=CLASS:unLike&&HREF:#/user/*/ EXTRACT=HREF
    TAB OPEN
    TAB T=3
    URL GOTO={{!EXTRACT}}
    TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=CLASS:followAction<SP>user-relation-action&&HREF:#&&TXT:Follow
    TAB CLOSE
    WAIT SECONDS=1
    TAG POS=4 TYPE=A ATTR=CLASS:unLike&&HREF:#/user/*/ EXTRACT=HREF
    TAB OPEN
    TAB T=3
    URL GOTO={{!EXTRACT}}
    TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=CLASS:followAction<SP>user-relation-action&&HREF:#&&TXT:Follow
    TAB CLOSE
    WAIT SECONDS=1
    TAG POS=5 TYPE=A ATTR=CLASS:unLike&&HREF:#/user/*/ EXTRACT=HREF
    TAB OPEN
    TAB T=3
    URL GOTO={{!EXTRACT}}
    TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=CLASS:followAction<SP>user-relation-action&&HREF:#&&TXT:Follow
    TAB CLOSE
    WAIT SECONDS=1
    TAB CLOSE
```

The part of viewing all likes works and opening the first photo too but when it tries to open a persons page it gives EXTRACT in the webaddress and multiple links..

Comment: It opens the Image, and then it extracts the list of likes. but when it starts following people it doesn't go to their page! Example of URL: http://iconosquare.com/viewer.php#/detail/905929510958619108_1529443797%5BEXTRACT%5D#EANF#%5BEXTRACT%5D#EANF#%5BEXTRACT%5D#EANF# instead of : http://iconosquare.com/viewer.php#/user/1495228766/ So it gives a weird URL and just doesn't load because it isn't a page.. It needs to open the users their pages and then follow them and then close and follow the next user who liked the image! But al it does is opening strange URLs and do nothing!

Comment: @macroscripts I've found out that I need to SET !EXTRACT to NULL every time! Then it works! But I am going to convert this to Imacros Javascript, so it can loop and I don't need to copy everything after SET NULL a 100 times!

Comment: @macroscripts i can't get it to work! Somehow I can't open .JS files and when it opens it just crashes while i did everything like everyone does... And I also can't use !LOOP in javascript?? or can I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that, the problem was that I need to SET !EXTRACT NULL before adding another value to it! That was the problem!

```
      VERSION BUILD=8881205 RECORDER=FX
        SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
        SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
        SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 2
        TAB T=1
        TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=A ATTR=CLASS:lienPhotoGrid&&HREF:#/detail/* EXTRACT=HREF
        TAB OPEN
        TAB T=2
        URL GOTO={{!EXTRACT}}
        TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=CLASS:unLike<SP>allCommentsLikes<SP>majuscule
        WAIT SECONDS=2
    SET !EXTRACT NULL
        TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=CLASS:unLike&&HREF:#/user/*/ EXTRACT=HREF
        TAB OPEN
        TAB T=3
        URL GOTO={{!EXTRACT}}
        WAIT SECONDS=3
        TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=CLASS:followAction<SP>user-relation-action&&HREF:#&&TXT:Follow
        TAB CLOSE
        WAIT SECONDS=1
SET !EXTRACT NULL
        TAG POS=2 TYPE=A ATTR=CLASS:unLike&&HREF:#/user/*/ EXTRACT=HREF
        TAB OPEN
        TAB T=3
        URL GOTO={{!EXTRACT}}
        TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=CLASS:followAction<SP>user-relation-action&&HREF:#&&TXT:Follow
        TAB CLOSE
```